# Find the greatest common divisor between $a$ and $b$ when $ 3a+5b=6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

As the tittle says, I need to find the greatest common divisor between $a$ and $b$ when $3a+5b=6$ and $(a,b) \neq 1$ and $(a,3)=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* Since $(a, b)$ divides the left hand side of $3a + 5b = 6$, it must divide the right hand side as well, so $(a, b) = 1, 2, 3$ or $6$. Now what does $(a, 3) = 1$ tell us about the possibilities?

Comment: (a, 3) = 1 tells us that "a" can't be divisible by 3. So "a" = 1, -1, 2 or -2.

Comment: @SantiagoPardal And then $(a,b)\ne 1$...

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, but thank you anyway.